Prove that the following series in a Hilbert space converges.
I need a HINT in the following problem :
I am trying to understand why if you have an arbitrary Hilbert Space and any Hilbert Basis then, the sum of the elements in the basis weighted with some square summable complex sequence will be guaranteed to have a limit.I attach my approach below, which was basically to show that the sequence will be Cauchy. I have tried to use the properties of the inner product and the orthogonality of the basis but I am stuck. Approach :


Hint: $(z_n)\in\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$ then what does it tell you about the tail part of this sequence.

I have noticed that the difference of two partial sums in H is actually the difference of two partial sums in C where this partial sums sum terms from z^2sequence. But z^2 is summable so it is Cauchy. Then, this implies that the sequence in H based on the z sequence is Cauchy and because H is complete then it will have some limit in the Hilbert space H. Is this the right reason why the limit exists?

Yes $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert so it suffices to show the partial sum Cauchy, but $z\in\ell_2$ implies for any $\varepsilon>0$, you can pick $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum^{+\infty}{k=N}|z_k|^2<\varepsilon$. And you can see $\displaystyle\sum^{N'}{k=N}|z_k|^2<\displaystyle\sum^{+\infty}_{k=N}|z_k|^2$ for any finite $N'$, and thus Cauchyness of $(s_n)$ is inherited from Cauchyness of $(z_n)$.
